# Password to Modify Prompt Disappearing

Tags: excel

I have an excel file which prompts the user for a password, or otherwise opens the file as Read-Only.

Only myself and one supervisor have the password.

Last week, went to open the file, and instead of the pw prompt, I was greeted with a "File.xlsm is locked for editing by 'another user'." message instead.

We changed the pw, thinking perhaps someone figured it out somehow... But the problem re-occurred, three times now. There is no owner file (~File.xlsm) and I have my folder settings set to show all.

When I go back to the General Options, where the pw is entered, the box is blank. Not sure what happened to the pw...

I've been scouring the net, but no one else seems to have had this issue - are you aware of anything that could be causing this?

I should note that this file is over two years old at this point, and we've never had any issues before.

Comment: I've had this message pop up randomly at times in different environments. Some times you just have to wait some time and the server catches up to itself and the file will open normally.

Comment: I have, too, but never on a pw protected file - no one should be able to lock it in the first place is my concern.

Comment: No, I don't mean that someone has it open and has locked it. I think it's a server glitch. I don't think it's locking "on purpose". I literally open files sometimes at the place I work, then close them, then reopen them a few moments later and it says its locked. I then wait a few more moments and its fine. Not saying this is *definitely* your case, but worth looking at.

Comment: This issue is not linked to the pwd protection, I have also seen it with files which are residing on a network drive. Typically your IT department should be able to "unlock" it.